# How do I select nodes that DO NOT have a particular child node?

Tags: xpath

A rather simple problem... XML Fragment:

```
<bean id='Juicer'>
    <property name="electric">
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id='Oven'>
    <property name="electric">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="wattage">
        <value>1000</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'm trying to write an xpath query that will select all `bean`s that do not have a `<property name="wattage">`.

I cant figure out how to say "beans not having this child" in xpath.

Note that I cannot rely on the "electric" property to be false each time the "wattage" is absent. (also, this example is kinda contrived).

Thanks :)

Comment: @Here-Be-Wolves: Good question (+1). See my answer for the simplest/shortest XPath expression so far, and its explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, after a little digging i figured it out:

```
//bean[not (property[@name='wattage'])]
```

Simple indeed :P

Comment: @Here-Be-Wolves: A minor problem: there is no element named `beans` in your provided XML...

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
//bean[not(property[@name='wattage'])]
```

Answer (score 2):

**In case the current node is the parent element of the `bean` elements, one XPath expression that selects the wanted elements is**:

```
bean[not(property/@name = 'wattage')]
```

**This is probably the simplest such expression** (has only a single predicate).

This expression translated in English says:

Select all `bean` children of the current node for which no `name` attribute of any of their `property` children is the string `"wattage"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//bean[not(@name = 'wattage')]
```

Comment: I believe that this query will return nodes like `<bean id='Oven'>`, because there exists a property (`electric`) whose @name is not `wattage`.